# Bluemix: Few folders/files doesn't come when we move the app to GIT

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

I was following Bluemix training and as per Exercise 4a . I wanted to move the app from bluemix to GitHub. After i moved the code i see few files are not coming

Like app.js and views/index.html files are not displayed .. Could anyone suggest me how to resolve this

Thanks,
pradeep

Comment: Can you post link to Exercise 4a?

Comment: https://developer.ibm.com/dwcourses/c4x/IBM_developerWorks/DW001/asset/IBM_Bluemix_Hands_on_Workshop_4a.pdf

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the button to add a Git repo in your Bluemix application dashboard, a new repository will be created on IBM DevOps Services containing the Starter Code for the runtime/boilerplate you used when creating the Bluemix application. So if you changed something on the application and then pushed it back to Bluemix, you won't see those changes in the newly created IDS repository.

If you didn't change anything you should actually see the same files you would see when downloading the Starter Code on your machine (*Getting Started* tab). 
If this doesn't happen you could, as a workaround, download the Starter Code on your machine first and then upload it on DevOps Services using the Upload function in *Edit Code* tab.